# Most relevant objectively-quantifiable reason to choose to use an object method vs. a function that just accepts the object as a parameter?

Tags: architectural-patterns, functions, methods

When writing code in a programming language that has the option of creating standalone functions vs. methods of a class or struct, what is the **most relevant objectively-quantifiable reason** to choose to implement any specific functionality as a method of the class or type instead of using an independent function that just accepts the object as a parameter?

*(This question completely changed from original — which
sfiss's answer was in response to — as the original was closed for for being unfocused.)*

Comment: I feel like this will be quite language specific.

Comment: i voted to close because "opinion-based", not "needs more focus

Comment: Would it make logical sense for the function to require access to an object of a class? If so, method. Otherwise, standalone function.

Comment: I don't see why one of the fundamental features of OO languages, must be "opinion-based" or "unfocussed". There must be design rationale, including from the language designers themselves.

Comment: @Steve sometimes there aren't "objectively-quantifiable reason[s]", just opinion-based ones

Comment: @Caleth, I think that was just nonsense retrofitted into the real question.

Answer (score 4):

One aspect of this is which paradigm you follow.

If its OOP, one rule of thumb could be: put it on the object if you need its internal state (dont violate law of Demeter, encapsulate state and expose behavior, tell dont ask), and else its a standalone function.

If its a functional approach, the struct is most likely only (immutable) Data, so standalone (pure) function works well.

I guess the most critical rule of thumb is: do it in a consistent way, whichever direction you choose.

Comment: In OOP, I'd say the key determinant is whether you want polymorphism or not. The `a` in `a.m(b, c)` is not equal to the `a` in `f(a, b, c)`. It (solely) determines the implementation of `m` that gets invoked.

Comment: @Alexander You can have a scheme where `b` and/or `c` get a say in it too.

Comment: @Caleth Yep, you can hand-roll single (or even multiple) dispatch with a plain function, but the point I was trying to convey is that most OOP languages give privileged behaviour to the `a` in `a.m(b, c)`, in that it gets single-dispatch automatically without you needing to hand roll anything.

Comment: @Alexander I meant you can do multiple dynamic dispatch with OO, and dispatch on the static  types of `a, b, c` is still polymorphic

Comment: @Caleth I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to how if you have function overloads all called `f`, that accept different types, that calling them with `a, b, c` will pick the correct one according to their static types? That's "ad hoc polymorphism". That's not "multiple _dynamic_ dispatch," because it happens at compile-time, based only on static types, without any runtime consideration of the concrete types being used. I was talking about runtime polymoprhism (["subtype polymorphism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping)).

Comment: But if (potentially multiple) dynamic dispatch is also possible for functions (Here: f(a) instead of a.f()), and thus we have polymorphism in both cases, that cant be the "key determinant"? Ofc that requires the language to support this, while most only support the a.f() case.

Comment: "But if (potentially multiple) dynamic dispatch is also possible for functions" Is it? It's certainly possible to design a lang that does that, I'm not aware of any languages that do automatic multiple dynamic dispatch based on the runtime type of all the args. Conversely, every mainstream language I know of that supports OOP (at a minimum: C++, Java, C#, Python, Ruby, JS, Swift and Rust) does single-dispatch on the `a` in `a.m(b, c)`. So I'd say that rule of thumb is definitely applicable, if you're in the the realm of mainstream languages like that, which is most likely the case.

Comment: @Alexander yes, static polymorphism is still polymorphism

Comment: @Caleth Sure. Amend my first comment to say "... whether you want _runtime subtype_ polymorphism or not", and I think my comments stand

Comment: @Alexander C# with `dynamic` allows multiple dynamic dispatch afaik. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch mentions several more or less popular languages. But I do agree with you that single dispatch is much more common

Comment: @sfiss Interesting, I've never seen `as dynamic` before!